# an exercise book for probability theory recommendation request

Tags: probability, reference-request

I'm looking for a good exercise book for probability theory, preferably at least partially with solutions to it. I want it to be detailed, not trivial, providing me solid fundamentals in the topic to be developed in the future. I'd wish it to be more of a "applied" technical university approach than the highly "abstract" one tailored for pure mathematics student at a university, however it need not to be so.

The topics I would like it to cover are more or less like in the part one of the book "Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Processes" by Papoulis and Pillai ( [table of contents](http://www.mhhe.com/engcs/electrical/papoulis/graphics/toc.pdf) ). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*One Thousand Exercises in Probability* by Grimmett and Stirzaker, Oxford Press, 2001 might suit your needs.

Comment: +1 I really doubt there's any better book for this purpose.The associated textbook by Grimmett and Stirzaker is also quite good,although fairly sophisticated.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 the textbook is indeed good, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

"A Collection of Exercises in Advanced Probability Theory" - the solutions manual of all even-numbered exercises from the book “A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory” (second edition, 2006) by Jeffrey S. Rosenthal :

http://www.worldscibooks.com/mathematics/6300_solutionsmanual.pdf

Comment: That link is dead :/